# Eclipse conditional breakpoints and global variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, conditional-statements, breakpoints

I have a global variable

```
static int debugNumber;
```

and a breakpoint with a condition

```
debugNumber > 1
```

with `Suspend thread`, `Conditional` and `Suspend when 'true'` checked. Currently, if I pause the execution of the program and hover over the declaration the value displayed is 2. Still, this breakpoint doesn't break.

As far as I can see on Google and here at SE `debugNumber > 1` should be fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just so we're clear: That line means: **If code execution gets to this line** (the line with the breakpoint), then do what breakpoints usually do: Freeze the thread (or if you've configured things to be that way, and pause all other threads, which is not the default). However, a conditional breakpoint means: Before breaking as usual, check the condition. If the condition is false, then don't do anything.

A conditional breakpoint is going to break as often, or less often, than a normal breakpoint, never more often.

It sounds like what you want is to 'breakpoint' every line in the codebase that *sets* the `debugNumber` variable, if the value it is being set to is 2 or higher. If that's what you want, make a 'watch' on `debugNumber` and configure the watch to break execution.

If that's not what you wanted, then, well, you made no mistakes in what you describes, so then it's one of a billion things that could be wrong:

- The line with your breakpoint was never hit.
- The debugNumber was 1 or less when it hit your breakpoint.
- You used 'run' to start your application and not 'debug' (there's pretty much no reason to ever 'run' anything, always pick 'debug')
- The global 'disable all breakpoints' toggle within eclipse has been toggled off. It's (unless you changed things) on the toolbar: a larger 'breakpoint dot' (blueish circle) with a big slash through it. It's a toggle button. Is it pressed in?
- Eclipse debugger has desynced. It will throw you a dialog if this happens, but one of the options in this dialog is 'ignore now and in the future' (It's a more succint text than that, but that's the gist of it). If you ever pressed that, it can desync. The debug view will tell you. This can happen if you change compiled code as eclipse runs, or change signatures in your source files and save the source file in the middle of a run.
- Many many more things

Comment: I rewrote the condition from scratch and suddenly it started working and has been doing that since then.